# Is there a way to rotate the bone faster with Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I always use the following code to rotate the bones.

```
bone.rotation_euler[0] = 30.0
bone.rotation_euler[1] = 30.0
bone.rotation_euler[2] = 30.0
```

However, this code seems to be slow.
Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2):

Besides setting all three at once, `bone.rotation_euler = [x,y,z]`, if you want to change all the bones at once, you can use foreach_set to do them in a batch

```
data = []
for bone in bones:
    rot_x = 30.0
    rot_y = 30.0
    rot_z = 30.0
    data += [rot_x, rot_y, rot_z]
bones.foreach_set("rotation_euler", data)
```

However this doesn't cause an update to the armature transforms (if you're looking at the bones in the viewport, nothing changes). The only way I could find to update is a normal assignment to any bone

```
# Forces armature transforms to be updated
bones[0].rotation_euler = bones[0].rotation_euler
```

This also probably explains why assigning the rotation_euler (or other pose properties) is slow: it causes a recalculation of all armature transforms.

Comment: I try to use this script: `bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones["testBone"].foreach_set("rotation_euler", [30.0,30.0,30.0])` . And I got an error: `AttributeError: 'PoseBone' object has no attribute 'foreach_set'` Why did it occur?

Comment: foreach_set only works if you're setting rotation_euler for _all bones_ at once, not if you only want to do one bone. You would do `bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones.foreach_set(...)`.

Comment: What should I do if I want each bone to have a discrete value? I get an error when I do the following for three bones
`bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones.foreach_set("rotation_euler", [[30.0,30.0,30.0],[20.0,20.0,20.0],[10.0,10.0,10.0]])`.

Comment: The array needs to be flattened. Please read the example code I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If by "slow" you mean slow to write, then how about using Python's tuple assignment:

```py
bone.rotation_euler = 30.0, 30.0, 30.0
```

Since all values are the same, you can use a list multiplication:

```py
bone.rotation_euler = [30.0]*3
```

And in this case you could use `30` instead of `30.0` - the value would be still converted to float:

```py
>>> my_object.rotation_euler
Euler((40.0, 40.0, 40.0), 'XYZ')

>>> my_object.rotation_euler = [30]*3
>>> my_object.rotation_euler
Euler((30.0, 30.0, 30.0), 'XYZ')
```

When in console, remember you can use very effective <kbd>Tab</kbd> autocompletion. You can use it in text block editing too, but there it's only based on existing words in current text block.

Comment: The meaning of my statement is not that it is slow to write, but that it is a matter of calculation time. And I am not assuming that all values are the same. In the case of

Comment: Hard to say why assigning a new Euler rotation to a bone would require optimization - perhaps there's some chain or dependencies, caused by some parenting, constraints, drivers... In this case, the tuple packing technique might be 3 times faster, because you assign the new rotation once, so everything else is recalculated only once...